# why boto not find config the file (Credentials)

Tags: python-2.7, unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

i Created new config file:

```
$ sudo vi ~/.boto
```

there i paste my credentials (as written in readthedocs for botp):

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = YOURACCESSKEY
aws_secret_access_key = YOURSECRETKEY
```

im trying to check connection:

```
import boto

boto.set_stream_logger('boto')
s3 = boto.connect_s3("us-east-1")
```

and my answer:

```
2014-11-26 14:05:49,532 boto [DEBUG]:Using access key provided by client.
2014-11-26 14:05:49,532 boto [DEBUG]:Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2014-11-26 14:05:50,539 boto [ERROR]:Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2014-11-26 14:05:50,540 boto [ERROR]:Unable to read instance data, giving up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/untitled.py", line 8, in <module>
    s3 = boto.connect_s3("us-east-1")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/__init__.py", line 141, in connect_s3
    return S3Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 190, in __init__
    validate_certs=validate_certs, profile_name=profile_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 569, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 975, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

why its not found the Credentials?
there is something that i did wrong?

Comment: You are doing a ``sudo`` when you edit the config file.  Are you also doing a sudo when you run python/boto?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is:
The string 'us-west-1' you provide as the first argument will be treat as the AWSAccessKeyID.

What you want is:

First creating a connection, note that a connection has no region or location info in it.

```
conn = boto.connect_s3('your_access_key', 'your_secret_key')
```

And then when you want to do some thing with the bucket, write the region info as an argument.

```
from boto.s3.connection import Location
conn.create_bucket('mybucket', location=Location.USWest)
```

or:

```
conn.create_bucket('mybucket', location='us-west-1')
```

> By default, the location is the empty string which is interpreted as the US Classic Region, the original S3 region. However, by specifying another location at the time the bucket is created, you can instruct S3 to create the bucket in that location.

Comment: So where should i put the region?

Comment: @Cuzi I just edited the answer, hope it can help you.